# Angular importing FormsModule in app.module vs child.module

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I'm using Angular with lazy loading modules. Each component has its own module. If I import a module in the root module (app.module) it must work fine. For example, I imported `HttpClientModule` in app.module and can use it in child components.

But about `FormsModule`, this doesn't work fine. I must import it in the child module, otherwise, I get the following errors:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
```

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407):

- if the module is imported for components, you’ll need to import it in each module needing them,
- if the module is imported for services, you’ll need to import it only once, in the first app module.

Answer (score 2):

create the SharedModule

```
@NgModule({

 imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

and add this to app.module.ts

```
 imports: [ SharedModule.forRoot(),
// Core Module
CoreModule.forRoot()]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution seems fine. But I need to know why this happen in `FormsModule` and not in `HttpClient` module.

Comment: Found the answer. Thanks.