# How Angular handles and builds multiple module imports in child modules

Tags: angular, ng-modules

I'm using LazyLoading modules in my Angular app. Imagine I have 3 routes. Home, about and contact. Also, I created a slider module (which I imported in about and contact).

After building my app, Angular creates a `js` file for each module (route) which is get downloaded after going through the specific route. Now the question is, how does it handle importing one slider module in two child modules? Does each `js` file contain the slider codes? Or any other strategy?

Comment: Importing `slidingModule` to all other module creates new state for each module.. so, in your case one `slidingModule` having two different state one for about and other for contact.. So, its better to import one time `slidingModule` in Your `app.module.ts`, you can get only one reference of it.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda It's not possible to import `SlidingModule` to `app.module.ts`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54957449/4055329